# Filestream is not changing offsets value

Tags: c#, filestream

i want to describe here my problem.
First of all i have got a file stream linked to an offset, and a byte array to replace.
To be more specific i provide my code here.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(fileNameGame, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            stream.Position = 0x6f360c;
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

However this will not change the value of the offset 0x6f360c...

Comment: Did you catch an exception?

Comment: I did not catch any exception it look like it works, but it does not at all.

Comment: How are you attempting to verify the value at file offset 0x6f360c?

Comment: As it is in the code, i enter value into textbox, which value is 6 digits long integer. Most of the time 512000.

Comment: If you want to see changes on disk immediately you need to either Close your stream or call Flush. FileStream is buffered.

Comment: Tried what you all recommended, still not working.

Comment: try stream.Seek(),then stream.Write().

Comment: Didn't work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: what you are trying is to start the write operation at a certain position right?

Comment: Yes.What i am trying is edit the value of 0x6f360c. It's current value is 1 000 000.

Comment: no what you show on the code is your first answer which is "yes",you are trying to write the data in textbox1  to the file starting to write that data at that specific location right?what do you mean about editing the hex value?

Comment: Yes, thats my point.

Comment: I just need a tip.. Still no success